# Cannot CIFilter image twice CGImage nil the seconds time

Tags: ios, uiimage, cifilter

I'm applying a filter to a filtered image in a custom UIImageView class so that when I set "hue" it filters the image. However, when I call the following code, [[self image] CGImage] the first time around returns the proper value. The second time around the [[self image] CGImage] is nil so the CIFilter return is also nil.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
- (void)setHue:(CGFloat)aHue
{
    hue = aHue;
    NSLog( @"CG Image? %@", [[self image] CGImage] );
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIHueAdjust"];
    [filter setDefaults];
    [filter setValue:[CIImage imageWithCGImage:[[self image] CGImage]]
              forKey:@"inputImage"];
    NSLog( @"Setting new hue %f", aHue );
    [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:aHue] forKey:@"inputAngle"];
    [self setImage:[UIImage imageWithCIImage:[filter valueForKey:@"outputImage"]]];

    NSLog( @"Output image %@", [self image] );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `UIImage` can be backed by either a `CGImage` or `CIImage`. After you run this function once and `[UIImage imageWithCIImage]` is called, the new `UIImage` is now backed by a `CIImage`.

This is actually good because the next time this function can be run even faster! You can simply check to see if `CIImage` exists and use it directly:

```
- (void)setHue:(CGFloat)aHue
{
    hue = aHue;
    NSLog( @"CG Image? %@", [[self image] CGImage] );
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIHueAdjust"];
    [filter setDefaults];
    if ([[self image] CGImage]) {
      [filter setValue:[CIImage imageWithCGImage:[[self image] CGImage]] forKey:@"inputImage"];
    }
    else {
      [filter setValue:[[self image] CIImage] forKey:@"inputImage"];
    }

    NSLog( @"Setting new hue %f", aHue );
    [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:aHue] forKey:@"inputAngle"];
    [self setImage:[UIImage imageWithCIImage:[filter valueForKey:@"outputImage"]]];

    NSLog( @"Output image %@", [self image] );
}
```